# Prove by Induction for Minimum Triangle Count in a General Position of $n$ Lines in a Plane

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, induction

Suppose we have ≥3 lines in general position in the plane. How to prove by induction that these lines form at least −2 triangles?

Here, the general position means that no two lines are parallel, and no three lines intersect.

I can imagine that if we add one line to a collection of  lines in general position, one triangle will be added because it will close the area between two lines in the outer surface. But I do not know whether my explanation is true, and make sense, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using the two definitions of general position you gave, you get that any 3 lines form a triangle. There are ${n}\choose{3}$ $\ge n-2$ such sets of 3 lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That makes sense, but I need prove by Induction.

Comment: To get the answer of $n-2$, I suspect that what OP wants is "triangular regions" aka with no lines within the region. So your approach will not work.